# My screen displays with a transparent black layer. How do I fix it?

Tags: screen

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04. After entering password, my screen displays with a transparent black layer. Please refer to the image:

[image]

Please solve my problem.

Comment: How did this happen? Was it after initial install or after some tinkering with graphics?

Comment: I was installing some graphics after that it happened. Can you please tell me how to fix the issue?

Comment: So remove these "some graphics".